# Maximizing distance between points on the positive surface of the unit hyper-sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Suppose we want to place $k$ ($k \geq 3$) points on the positive surface of a unit hyper-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geq 3$),  where all coordinates of a point are positive, such that the minimum distance, $x$, between any pair of points is maximized. Is there a general formula to determine the value $x$?

Comment: Why do you want all coordinates positives? This would be only 1/8 of a standard sphere in $\mathbb {R}^3$ say.

Comment: Equidistribution over the entire sphere is more standard and if you have a lower bound for the min distance over the whole surface it will also hold for the positive quadrant as well since deleting points only increases min distances between points.

Comment: For the sphere in $\mathbb {R}^3$ you may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere)

Comment: I have no hard reasons, but given that there are no such formulas for spheres, balls (solid spheres), cubes, ... etc, I highly doubt that there is one for the positive part of a sphere.